# serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Acceso denegado.', None, 5)?

Tags: python-3.x

a small query, I am learning about web servers with web.py, but when executing the code it produces an error.

```
import web
from web import form
import serial
```

the serial port works correctly...

```
port = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

render = web.template.render('templates')

urls = (
'/', 'index')
```

we read humidity from an arduino via pyserial ...

```
class index:
  submit_form = form.Form(
  form.Textbox('Temperature', description='Temperature'),
  form.Button('submit', type="submit", description='submit')
  )

    def GET(self):
      f = self.submit_form()
      f.validates()
      line = port.readline()
      if line:
        data = float(line)
        humidity = relativeHumidity(line, 25)
        return render.base(f, humidity)
      else:
        return render.base(f, "Not valid data")

    def POST(self):
     f = self.submit_form()
     f.validates()
     temperature = f['Temperature'].value
     line = port.readline()
     if line:
        data = float(line)
        humidity = relativeHumidity(line, float(temperature))
        return render.base(f, humidity)
    else:
        return render.base(f, "Not valid data")

def relativeHumidity(data, temperature):
  volt = float(data) / 1024 * 5.0
  sensorRH = 161.0 * volt / 5.0 - 25.0
  trueRH = sensorRH / (1.0546 - 0.0026 * temperature)
  return trueRH

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = web.application(urls, globals())
  app.run()
```

HTML files are correct ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing

```py
C:\>python -m pip install PySerial
```

and closing the terminal of Arduino, not the IDE, only the terminal